# Allowing a duplicate title for a question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, title

I often hit the restriction that does not allow a title of a question to be one that already exists. As a result, I would have to add extra words that do not add much information, just to make the title unique.

The URL pointing to a question has a numerical ID, so I don't think this restriction works for realizing unique URL. Furthermore, titles can be edited, so titles are not crucial for identifying a page. In fact, a URL with a numerical ID alone without a title works for redirecting a page, so I believe this restriction does not have anything to do with URL issue.

I guess the intention behind it was to force a title to be descriptive enough. But I don't think this restriction is working in that way. In the earlier days of Stack Overflow, relatively shorter titles were more likely to be accepted because it was less likely to hit a duplicate title already taken in the past. As years pass by, you are required to make the title longer and longer. This has nothing to do with whether the title is descriptive enough or not.

Why not remove this restriction? I don't think it is making much sense.

Comment: Could you, perhaps, provide an example (preferably multiple examples) of (a) title(s) that didn't work?

Comment: Can you provide an example of a title for which this was a problem?

Comment: This happens pretty often, and I don't think it is usefult to just pick a few, but a recent one is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554428/ruby-on-rails-routing-error-following-tutorial, whose title I tried to edit to "Ruby on Rails routing error", but was rejected because of duplication.

Comment: @sawa: what's wrong with the original title that's fixed with the new one?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy You don't seem to understand my point. The particular question I linked is not important for this question here.

Comment: @sawa I think the point is that if you can't give one example where it *is* important, it's not important.

Answer (score 9):

If the title is descriptive enough and identical it's probably about the same topic, so why do you need to ask the same question again?

If the title is too general is not useful for searching and indexing purposes and should be therefore improved and better specified.

Comment: Same comment as with djechin: You do not seem to understand what I wrote. As I wrote above, if the purpose was to make the title descriptive enough, checking for duplicates does not help because shorter titles were allowed in the past. A better restriction could be an absolute one, that does not depend on the existence of other questions.

Comment: I don't see why removing the restriction would benefit anyone. It would just allow users to post non-descriptive titles.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for your example of [Ruby on rails routing error following tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554428/ruby-on-rails-routing-error-following-tutorial).  See though - that's exactly a bad title because it's not useful to other visitors.  Say I have  a Ruby on Rails error while following a tutorial.  Your question fits my situation perfectly, yet the chances that we have the same problem are approximately 0%.

If you had a title more like, say, "Not redirected from localhost when following Ruby on Rails tutorial," and I have that problem, it's *very* likely we'll match.

To your original proposal:  If two questions have the same title, why are they not the same question?  And if they're different questions, they should have different titles.  Titles should be quite informative.  More concision is needed than in the question, but make them longer if it's what you need to make them specific.

Comment: You do not seem to understand what I wrote. As I wrote above, if the purpose was to make the title descriptive enough, checking for duplicates does not help because shorter titles were allowed in the past. A better restriction could be an absolute one, that does not depend on the existence of other questions.

Comment: @sawa it doesn't need to catch every case to be useful. If you can come up with an absolute way to detect if a title is useful, you probably would have made a breakthrough in artificial intelligence in general.

More concretely, they would have the same URL...