# Can I ask different questions with the same title twice on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, title

I want to ask two different questions with the same title on Stack Overflow. Is this possible?

If it is not then why can I not? I have two different purposes for the same title. We cannot explain our whole problem in the title. That's why we should go for the body part for giving more clarification. I want my title to be the same for the two posts, but the body parts to be different.

Comment: The title is your main advert for your question. If it's 'I have a probelm' people will pass rather than answering it. Make it as good and specific as possible.

Comment: This is a strange request, two different questions needing exactly the same title is hard to imagine, an example would help clear this up a bit. Even then it seems this may not be possible: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202747/allowing-a-duplicate-title-for-a-question

Answer (score 15):

**If it's a different question, you should use an (at least slightly) different title.**

When you go on to ask a question on a Stack Exchange website, the tip above the title field tells you to:
<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

> **Be specific** and imagine you’re asking a question to another person

If you find yourself wanting to re-use the same title of one of your other questions, chances are, the title is too general, to begin with, and shouldn't be used for *either* of the questions. Remember that the title of the question is the main tool you have to get people interested in the question.

So, your goal is to use a title that is interesting, specific enough, and not too long at the same time (there's a body field to include more information as you indicated).

Moreover:

- **DO** search about the problem first and make sure your question isn't a duplicate.
- **Do NOT** use the tag name in the title (that's what tags are for).

You didn't use any examples so let me provide one. Suppose you have two questions about using an array. Instead of trying to ask two questions with this title:

> How to use arrays in javascript?

..consider using something like:

> How can I get an element from an array by index?

..and:

> How can I remove an element from an array by index?

Answer (score 11):

No, this is not possible; titles have to be unique. (I guess you could try adding extra whitespace inside to circumvent this restriction, but that's a bad idea.)

There's an [FAQ page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10648/295232) with some good advice on how to write good titles:

> The purpose of a title is to attract people interested in your topic or who can give you an answer. People scan web pages quickly; make it easy for them to notice your question and understand what your question is about.
>
> Make sure you describe your question or problem well enough so that readers get the gist of what it's about

If you use the same title for two different questions, it fails in its purpose to make people who *volunteer* to research your problem to quickly understand what your questions are about.