# Can I use a title with an error message on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, title

I wanted to make a title like this:

```
Laravel 6 Error: GET http://localhost/fonts/vendor/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfa-solid-900.woff2?55071ae1abc18726e23174192ebc0b68 net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

Can I do this? Does this make sense?

Comment: No, it is too long

Comment: I am here for seeking help from you. But you people discourage me by giving a negative vote on my question. Please give me some suggestions that how can I improve my limitation on this particular segment.

Comment: @AshifulIslamPrince The negative votes could be because your question is off-topic, and because people might not think it's a good question.  See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354906/can-i-ask-the-different-questions-with-the-same-title-twice-on-stack-overflow#comment1185820_354906) comment on your previous question about titles.

Comment: If you have a question that only matters to a single site, use the per site meta. Your questions receive downvotes because they are off topic here (not about the whole network, just SO). If you have a question specific to SO, please use https://meta.stackoverflow.com/ Based on you last few questions, you should read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title to find some help with titles.

Comment: Thank you sir for your guidelines and information.@MarkKirby

Comment: `I am here for seeking help from you` I count two answers, did they not help you? Can you post a link to a question that has an error message in its title? How many can you find?  What did the users write in the body? Is there a detailed description of the problem and a list of solutions the user tried before posting?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend it. No one is going to be able to tell what's happening. A good title lets someone know if the question is worth their time.

'laravel is unable to get webfonts from localhost' (feel free to add a little more )

For example is significantly more descriptive. You can then talk about what you are trying to do and how it's failing *then* include the error message

It is essentially a thesis statement for the rest of your post.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the intention was good. People tend to search error messages. But we also need to consider that SEO of any SE site is excellent. Having the error message in the body is equally fine when it comes to getting it in search engines indexing.

A good title makes the users of the site want to click the question. An error message in the title makes it not so tempting to click.

Not sure why you wanted to do so, but that's what came to my mind.